# Problema com inserção de dados em tabela via laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller, model

Estou com um projeto em laravel ao mesmo tempo que aprendo a usar a framework, preciso inserir um determinado valor em um campo de uma tabela, para isso existe uma condição que coloquei no controller:

```
public function setExpert()
{
    if($concessionaria->user_id = 0)
    {
        $concessionaria->expert = 0;
        $concessionaria->save();
    }
    else
    {
        $concessionaria->expert = 1;
        $concessionaria->save();
    }
```

A ideia é criar um botão em que um especialista possa deixar de ser especialista em uma concessionaria, para isso criei uma condição que se já exista um especialista em uma determinada concessionária o valor de um campo booleano seja setado como 0(não_tem_especialista, isso quando ele apertar esse botão) automaticamente, e se não exista será setado como 1(ao apertar o botão), não sei se ficou claro, se for necessário eu explico denovo.
Essa é a model com os dados que preciso:

```
class ConcessionariaDelete extends Model
{
public $table = "concessionaria";

public $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'expert',
    'nome',
    'expert_da_concessionaria',
    'slug',
    'tipo',
    'area',
    'cep',
    'endereco',
    'view_count',
    'status',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
];
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esses são os campos que precisam ser alterados

O que eu fiz criar foi uma model para gerenciar a tabela do banco de dados, e um controller ligado a model com as condições para setar se é ou não especialista, o meu problema esta sendo para executar a função, eu preciso só recarregar a pagina? é necessário colocar ela em alguma pagina para ser executada? Eu não entendi corretamente como faço para as condições do meu controller fazerem alterações no meu banco de dados.

Comment: Posso te ajudar, mas antes preciso entender um pouco melhor a estrutura do seu projeto. Cada concessionária terá apenas um especialista? Quais são as ações que esse especialista fará dentro do seu projeto?

Comment: A ideia é que cada concessionaria tenha 3 especialistas, ele se torna especialista a partir de pontos que ele faz no decorrer da carreira, mas ainda não fiz um botão para deixar de ser especialista, pretendo usar a função setExpert() em um botão feito em javascript via ajax, o problema é que não estou conseguindo atribuir essa função ao botão, e mesmo que consiga não sei se vai funcionar, acredito que apenas de eu recarregar o meu banco de dados já deveria aparecer as mudanças que condicionei em setExpert().

Comment: Tem que ver os demais campos não são obrigatórios se for é preciso passar no cadastro caso seja um update está errado

Answer (score 0):

o Eloquent não deve estar identificando a chave primária da tabela.

```
class ConcessionariaDelete extends Model
{
 ...
 protected $primaryKey = "sua chave primária"
 ...
```

Comment: Não é preciso especificar se o nome for ID o laravel interpreta já o ID como primaryKey

Answer (score 0):

Caso seja um update segue um exemplo:

```
public function setExpert($id)
{
   $concessionaria =  Model::find($id);
   if($concessionaria->expert === 0){
        $concessionaria->expert = 0;  
   }else{
     $concessionaria->expert = 1;
   }


   $concessionaria->save();

}
```